# Map array to get specific value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im trying to map an array to get a specific value and output it in my PodcastList component.

My json (the red underline is what I want to be viewed in PodcastList.js)
https://itunes.apple.com/se/rss/toppodcasts/limit=100/genre=1314/explicit=true/json
[image]
**This is my Home component:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { fetchPopularPodcasts } from './api'
import PodcastList from './PodcastList'

export default class Home extends Component {

  state = {
    podcasts: [],
    loading: true,
  }

  async componentDidMount () {
    const podcasts = await fetchPopularPodcasts();
      this.setState({
            podcasts,
            loading: false,
        })
  }

  render() {
    const { podcasts } = this.state

    return (
      <div className='container'>
                        <PodcastList list={podcasts} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**This is my PodcastList component**

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import slugify from 'slugify'

const PodcastList = ({ list }) => {
  return (
        <div className='col-md-12'>
        {list.map((pod) => {
          return (
                    <div className='pod-box'>
            GET THE LABEL?????
                    </div>
        )
        })}
        </div>
  )
}


export default PodcastList;
```

**This is my Api.js**

```
import Feed from 'feed-to-json-promise'

export async function fetchPopularPodcasts () {
  const response = await fetch('https://itunes.apple.com/se/rss/toppodcasts/limit=100/genre=1314/explicit=true/json')
  const podcasts = await response.json()
  return podcasts.feed.entry
}

export async function fetchPodcast (podId) {
  const response = await fetch(`https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=${podId}&country=se`)
  const podcasts = await response.json()

  return podcasts.results
}

export async function fetchPodcastEpisodes (feedUrl) {
  const feed = new Feed()
  const episodes = await feed.load(feedUrl)

  return episodes
}
```

Comment: Are you just trying to get an array of the values in the label property? Or what specifically do you want your output to look like?

Comment: No, It didn't help that image in order to understand.

Comment: What do you mean by "map through"?

Comment: Yes exactly @mhodges ..

Comment: Have you looked at this javascript map function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map ?

Comment: It would help if you could create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Well assuming your data all conforms to the same structure, you could do `data.map(elem => elem["im:artist"].attributes.label)`, where `elem` is each outer object, and the `["im:artist"].attributes.label` is a fixed path to the value you are looking for on each object

Comment: Related, possibly duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json

Comment: Ok.. I updated my question, sorry for being neewbie. Im in the learning phase of React, so I have a hard time to describe what in want to accomplish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get an array containing the label property of each array item object, you can use Array's [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method:

```
let list = [ /* the contents included in your screenshot */ ]

let newList = list.map(pod => { 
    return pod['im:artist'].attributes.label 
})
```

Note that because of the way the property 'im:artist' is formatted -- i.e., with a colon -- you'll need to access it using [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Objects_and_properties).

Also, ensure that list is actually an array using the inspector.

Finally, for your case in PodcastList:

```
const PodcastList = ({ list }) => {
    return (
        <div className='col-md-12'>
            {
                list.map(pod => {
                    return (
                        <div className='pod-box'>
                            pod['im:artist'].attributes.label 
                        </div>
                    )
                 })
            }
        </div>
    )
}
```

This assumes all of your React-ness is correct, as in that domain, I'm unfamiliar. (If it's still not working, I would investigate if you need curly braces in your innermost div.)

**Also, upon reassessing your code, you'd probably rather use forEach as you're not really trying to create a mapped array; rather, you're trying to gain access to a property for each array element.**

Comment: Now I understand! Thanks! :-)  And in cases like in my json, where the property im:image contains an array? How can i access that?

Comment: @JonasAlvarson you would go: pod['im:image'][index], where index is a number representing a position in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Your child component would be set up in the same way as the  component

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import slugify from 'slugify'

const default class PodcastList extends Component {

  _renderList = () => {
    let elem = this.props.list && this.props.list.length > 0
      (this.props.list.map((pod) => {
        <div className='pod-box'>{pod}</div>;
      )});
    return elem;
  }

  render() {
    return (
       <div className='col-md-12'>
        {this._renderList()}
       </div>
    )
  }
```

export default PodcastList;